# How to draw Trend Line in Asp.Net MVC Kendo Column Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I am using Kendo Dataviz controls to render my Asp.Net MVC Column Chart. Everything is going well so far but now I am stuck with drawing the trend lines in Column Chart. Looked around in Kendo documentation but couldn't find any answer. Anyone's help will really be appreciated.

Following is the code snippet of my chart rendering

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
      .Name("Column-Chart")
      .Series(series =>
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < Model.ListColumnsDataArray.Count; j++)
            {
                if (Model.lstPageAndWidgetsData[i].Report.ChartType == "Column")
                    series.Column(Model.ListColumnsDataArray[i].DataArray).Name(Model.ListColumnsDataArray[i].ColumnName).Tooltip(true);
            }
        })
        .CategoryAxis(axis => axis.Categories(Model.ListColumnsDataArray[0].DataArray)
                                  .Labels(rotation => rotation.Rotation(-45)))
        .Tooltip(true)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "widgets-height-width" })
 )
```

Comment: It seems that Kendo chart does not have any trendline functionality (unlike Excel), here is a solution that may help you to draw a trendline http://tylerramsey.net/2015/03/29/trendy-with-trendlines-part2.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. I have already seen that example but my problem is I am using ASP.NET MVC chart rendering rather JQuery. I can't change my chart rendering mechanism as I am dealing with quite a complex situation. Is there any other example where I can build my model with line axis along with the column chart axis?

Comment: You can still add the html5 version of the graph even though you're using mvc.  The html5 version actually has greater documentation and supports more customizing over the razor version.